# How to check mongodb time series collection shard distribution

Tags: mongodb, sharding

```
[direct: mongos] test> db.weather.getShardDistribution()
MongoshInvalidInputError: [SHAPI-10001] Collection weather is not sharded
```

we are getting this error and how to check the sharded collection data distribution for time series collection.
Please share the details with query output if any one have already working on sharded time series collection.

Below is the command i used to create time series sharded collection
sh.shardCollection( “test.weather”, { “uid”: 1 }, { timeseries: { timeField: “et”, metaField: “uid” ,granularity: “hours” } })

Comment: What is the output from the `sh.status()` (this needs to be run from the `mongos` router of your sharded cluster).

Answer (score 0):

Which mongo shell do you use?

As far as I remember command `getShardDistribution()` was not working in older `mongosh` version. Update Mongo shell to latest version, I assume then it will work.

Another option is `sh.getShardedDataDistribution()` command:

```
sh.getShardedDataDistribution().toArray().filter(x=> x.ns == 'test.weather').shift().shards

[
  {
    shardName: 'shard_02',
    numOrphanedDocs: 0,
    numOwnedDocuments: 32707096,
    ownedSizeBytes: Long('5854570184'),
    orphanedSizeBytes: 0
  },
  {
    shardName: 'shard_01',
    numOrphanedDocs: 0,
    numOwnedDocuments: 32680397,
    ownedSizeBytes: Long('5849791063'),
    orphanedSizeBytes: 0
  },
  {
    shardName: 'shard_04',
    numOrphanedDocs: 0,
    numOwnedDocuments: 35894266,
    ownedSizeBytes: Long('5635399762'),
    orphanedSizeBytes: 0
  },
  {
    shardName: 'shard_03',
    numOrphanedDocs: 0,
    numOwnedDocuments: 30664963,
    ownedSizeBytes: Long('5458363414'),
    orphanedSizeBytes: 0
  }
]
```

Or you query it manually:

```
db.getSiblingDB("config").chunks.aggregate([
   { $lookup: { from: "collections", localField: "uuid", foreignField: "uuid", as: "collection" } },
   { $set: { collection: "$$REMOVE", balancing: { $not: { $first: "$collection.noBalance" } }, ns: { $first: "$collection._id" } } },
   { $match: { ns: 'data.sessions.20231230' } },
   { $group: { _id: { shard: "$shard", ns: "$ns", balancing: "$balancing", uuid: "$uuid" }, chunks: { $count: {} } } },
  // { $group: { _id: { ns: "$_id.ns", uuid: "$_id.uuid", balancing: "$_id.balancing" }, sum: { $sum: "$chunks" }, shards: { $push: { shard: "$_id.shard", chunks: "$chunks" } } } },
])
```

Just a note, in earlier MongoDB versions, the balancer distributed data to have even number of *chunks* across the shards. In current released the goal is to get even data *sizes*.